# Rails 4.2 ActionMailer: no implicit conversion of Message into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am delivering the mail message from

```
class DelayMessageJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    message = self.arguments.first
    MessageMailer.default(message).deliver_now!
    message[:sent] = true
    message.save
  end

end
```

it's running fine until there... scheduled then enqueued

my MessageMailer class is quite simple

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def default(message)
    @content = message.text
    mail(
      to: "#{message[:recipient_email]}",
      subject: "Hi and welcome"
      )
  end
end
```

and it's parent ApplicationMailer

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

debugging the MessageMailer class, I can get the message arg ..

```
#<Message id: 19, recipient_email: "yves@icloud.com", text: "retesting", 
delay_until_time: "2015-07-29 15:14:00", timezone_offset: 2, 
sent: false, created_at: "2015-07-29 15:13:48", 
updated_at: "2015-07-29 15:13:48"
```

mail is raising: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Message into Hash`

UPDATE 1

I changed `message[:sent]` to `message.sent`, same error

```
8:06:17 sidekiq.1  | 2015-07-30T06:06:17.365Z 4871 TID-oxt3zobs8
                       WARN: {
                         "class"=>"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper", 
                         "wrapped"=>"DelayMessageJob",
                         "queue"=>"default", "args"=> [{
                           "job_class"=>"DelayMessageJob",
                           "job_id"=>"9f1b52c0-bb4a-479c-bb5c-5ca11ae257b0",
                           "queue_name"=>"default",
                           "arguments"=>[{"_aj_globalid"=>"gid://delay-message-on-rails/Message/23"}]
                         }],
                         "retry"=>true,
                         "jid"=>"8cbffb19c9d88c48e9b9aa00",
                         "created_at"=>1438236297.952947,
                         "enqueued_at"=>1438236377.2572238,
                         "error_message"=>"no implicit conversion of Message into Hash",
                         "error_class"=>"TypeError",
                         "failed_at"=>1438236377.3641548, "retry_count"=>0
                       }
08:06:17 sidekiq.1 | 2015-07-30T06:06:17.365Z 4871 TID-oxt3zobs8
                       WARN: TypeError: no implicit conversion of Message into Hash
```

the error seems to be raised upon message being enqueued ...

Comment: I think you are getting error here  `message[:sent] = true`

Comment: try this `message.sent = true` in place of `message[:sent] = true`

Comment: thanks I tried it , same error .. see UPDATE 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I want to send emails in background, using sidekiq, I should not forget to start sidekiq 'mailers' queue in my Procfile

```
sidekiq:     sidekiq -q devise,1 -q default -q mailers
```

I can send delayed notifications using directly ActionMailer or using ActiveJob

**1-  using ActionMailer**

controllers/messages_controler.rb

```
 MessageMailer.keep_inform(@message).deliver_later(wait_until: @message[:delay_until_time])
```

mailers/message_mailer.rb

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def keep_inform(notification)
    @content = notification.text
    mail(
      to: "#{notification.recipient_email}",
      subject: "Hi and welcome"
      )
  end
end
```

**2-  using ActiveJobs**

controllers/messages_controler.rb

```
DelayMessageJob.set(wait_until: @message[:delay_until_time]).perform_later(@message)
```

jobs/delay_message_jobs.rb

```
class DelayMessageJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default
  def perform(notification)
    MessageMailer.keep_inform(notification).deliver_now
    notification.sent = true
    notification.save
  end
end
```

**In both case :**
I  defined my mailers/messages_mailer.rb

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer  
  def keep_inform(notification)
    @content = notification.text
    mail(
      to: "#{notification.recipient_email}",
      subject: "Hi and welcome"
      )
  end
end
```

NOTE: 
I don't know if it's important, but I changed the term 'message' to 'notification', I guess 'message' is used internally ...

Comment: If this is your final answer, then please mark it as accepted, in order to mark the question as complete.